# Java method definition issue

Tags: java, methods

The method is defined as below:

```
public static void checkNotNull<T extends Throwable>(Object value, String name, Class<T> exceptionClass) 
{

}
```

then the compiler throws some error:

**Multiple markers at this line

```
- void is an invalid type for the variable checkNotNull
- Duplicate field ValidationUtility.value
- Syntax error on token ">", Identifier expected after this token
- The type Class is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with 
 arguments <T>
- The type Class is not visible
- Duplicate field ValidationUtility.exceptionClass
- T cannot be resolved to a type
- Syntax error, insert ";" to complete FieldDeclaration
- Duplicate field ValidationUtility.String**
```

Is anything wrong? Please help me, thank you.

Comment: Yes, you didn't post all the code.

Comment: It basically a missing brace or semicolon. Format your code in the IDE and check. post your code if possible.

Comment: Please provide compelete minimal code that gives the error.

Comment: Why do you have a class declaration inside a method call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`void checkNotNull<T extends Throwable>(...,Class<T> exceptionClass)` is a wrong syntax. It Should be `<T extends Throwable>void checkNotNull(...,Class<T> exceptionClass)`

```
public static <T extends Throwable> void checkNotNull(Object value, String name, 
                                                      Class<T> exceptionClass) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `<T extends Throwable>` before void.

```
public static <T extends Throwable> void checkNotNull(Object value, String name,
Class<T> exceptionClass) {}
```

You can refer to [Generics Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html)

[JLS#8.4. Method Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4)

```
MethodHeader:
     MethodModifiersopt TypeParametersopt Result MethodDeclarator Throwsopt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <T extends Throwable> void checkNotNull(Object value, String name, Class<T> exceptionClass) 
{

}
```